# Take a photo from a service worker notification

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, notifications, service-worker

I have a PWA and I want to directly take (and upload) a photo if the user clicks the action button of the notification.

target system is chrome mobile.

I'm using an input element to open the users camera:

```
<input id="photo" type="file" accept="image/\*" capture\>
```

The notification is triggered from a service worker and when the user clicks the action I need to "click" the input element. Therefore in the service worker I get the correct client (the page) and do a `client.postMessage()` to notify the page context.

My problem:
It seems on the page context I don't have the "user-initiated event" flag, despite my original event is user triggered.
Error: `File chooser dialog can only be shown with a user activation`.

Looks like my `client.postMessage()` is not forwarding it or service worker notifications don't have/support it at all.
I "forwarding" via `postMessage()` works at least with frames via User Activation V2 of Chrome.
see https://mustaqahmed.github.io/user-activation-v2/api-consistency/postMessages.html

Any ideas? (besides directing the user to a page and have him click a button again)

code snippets:

website:

```
const registration = navigator.serviceWorker.register("./service_worker.js", {
    scope: "/",
}).then((registration) => {
    console.log("Service Worker registered");

    navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
        console.log("client side service worker message event received");
        if (!event.data || !event.data.command) {
            return;
        }
        if (event.data.command === 'notification_take') {
            console.log("client side notification_take");
            picker_take.click(); // here we get the error
        }
    });

    Notification.requestPermission(function (status) {
        if (status == 'granted') {
            console.log("Notification permission granted");
            
            upload_service_worker_reg.showNotification("Test", {
                "body": "",
                "tag": "take_photo",
                "image": "",
                "icon": "./img/favicon.png",
                "badge": "",
                "renotify": false,
                "actions": [
                    { "action": "notification_take", "title": " Take" },
                ],
                "silent": true,
                "persistent": true,
                "requireInteraction": true,
                "sticky": true,
                "notificationCloseEvent": false
            });
        }
    });
});
```

service worker:

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
    console.log("notificationclick event triggered");

    if (event.action === 'notification_take') {
        console.log("notificationclick event triggered, notification_take action");
        event.waitUntil(
            self.getClient(clients).then(client => {
                if (client) {
                    client.postMessage({ "command": "notification_take" });
                }
            })
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: doesn't matter if PWA app is installed or not